# Can't get clipboard forwarding working, while being in Docker under SSH

Tags: ssh, docker, clipboard

1. I have SSH connection to the server without X session. I've set up SSH to forward X. When I get connected to that server over SSH and type:

> user@host-machine:~$ ssh remote-server
>
> user@remote-server:~$ echo hello | xsel -bi

all goes right - I'm getting "hello" on my host's clipboard.

2. I have simple Docker image based on Ubuntu. I run the the image with following parameters: `docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix myimage bash`. Then, being inside container I'm typing:

> user@host-machine:~$ docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix myimage bash
>
> user@92c40ac9feb7:~$ echo hello | xsel -bi

all goes right - I'm getting "hello" on my host's clipboard.

3. Now I want to run Docker image on those server being under SSH session with X forwarding enabled. When I'm trying to copy something to the clipboard in this configuration, I'm getting following error:

> user@host-machine:~$ ssh remote-server
>
> user@remote-server:~$ docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix myimage bash
>
> user@688e48e4b90a:~$ echo hello | sudo xsel -bi
>
> xsel: Can't open display: (null)
>
> : Connection refused
>
> user@688e48e4b90a:~$

Why I can't get clipboard forwarding working, while being in Docker container under SSH session?

Comment: Have you tried interactive mode? `docker run -it ...` Maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/327aen/copying_text_to_host_clipboard/ could help